# P2P MultiCoin markets

Tags: currencies, market

are there any p2p markets for  different kinds of coins, like https://localbitcoins.com/ for bitcoins?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Yes!

Bitsquare.io is:

1. Decentralized – there is no single point of failure.
2. Safe – Bitsquare never holds your funds.
3. Instantly accessible – no need for approval from a central
   authority.
4. Private -no one except trading partners exchange personally
   identifying data.
5. Open – every aspect of the project is transparent.
6. Easy – we take usability seriously.

Many altcoins are supported:
https://bitsquare.io/faq/#altcoins

Here you can see the list of the currently supported altcoins:

“ETH”, “Ethereum”
“DAO”, “DAO”
“LTC”, “Litecoin”
“XMR”, “Monero”
“NMC”, “Namecoin”
“DASH”, “Dash”
“SDC”, “ShadowCash”
“NBT”, “NuBits”
“NSR”, “NuShares”
“PPC”, “Peercoin”
“XPM”, “Primecoin”
“FAIR”, “FairCoin”
“SC”, “Siacoin”
“SJCX”, “StorjcoinX”
“GEMZ”, “Gemz”
“DOGE”, “Dogecoin”
“MKR”, “Maker”
“BLK”, “Blackcoin”
“FCT”, “Factom”
“NXT”, “Nxt”
“STEEM”, “STEEM”
“BTS”, “BitShares”
“XCP”, “Counterparty”
“XRP”, “Ripple”
“XEM”, “NEM”
“ANTI”, “Anti.cash”
“VPN”, “VPNCoin”
“MAID”, “MaidSafeCoin”
“YBC”, “YbCoin”
“CLOAK”, “CloakCoin”
“EGC”, “EverGreenCoin”
“VRC”, “VeriCoin”
“ESP”, “Espers”
“XVG”, “Verge”
“MYR”, “Myriadcoin”
“MXT”, “MarteXcoin”
“GRS”, “Groestlcoin”
“IOC”, “I/O Coin”
“SIB”, “Sibcoin”
“CRBIT”, “Creditbit”
“BIGUP”, “BigUp”
“XPTX”, “PlatinumBar”
“JBS”, “Jumbucks”
“PINK”, “Pinkcoin”
“OK”, “OKCash”
“GRC”, “Gridcoin”
“MOIN”, “Moin”
“SLR”, “SolarCoin”
“SHIFT”, “Shift”
“ERC”, “Europecoin”
“POST”, “PostCoin”

Comment: Thanks  alot for  link, but  "If you’re interested in helping make Bitsquare a reality, there are many ways to contribute.". Doesn't look like  something production ready.

May be any other options?

Comment: @alex It is production ready and already being used! https://www.reddit.com/r/moneromarkets/comments/4l8wy1/bitsquare_trade_request/  More liquidity will come in time. No other P2P exchange offers nearly as many altcoins. Here is one more option: http://dogecoindark.net/i2pexchange/

Comment: @YaoChoa ok, got it. Thank you for response, but may be there are any  options? I don't say Bitsquare is bad, I just need list to choose from.

Comment: @alex there are specific P2P exchanges for a few alts such as LTC and XMR: https://www.litecoinlocal.net/ https://www.moneroclub.com/  Some sellers on Mycelium and LocalBitcoins also will sell alts such as ETH